# How to map string to a object member?

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
class Test {
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;
  //there are quite a few variables here.
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
string input;
Test test;
if(input == "a") {
  return test.a;
} else if(input == "b") {
 return test.b;
} else if (input == "c") {
 return test.c;
}
```

Is there a way that I can do these "if-else" chains smarter, like a mapping?

Comment: There are many alternatives, all with different levels of complexity or runtime considerations.  What are your primary concerns?  It's hard to answer this question as currently written, without just dumping on you a whole bunch of options that might not be suitable for your intended purpose.

Comment: Furthermore, the "quite many variables" comment is not clear enough.  Are they all `double`?  Are the names all one character in length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the members are the same type, then you can use a `std::map` of pointer-to-members, eg:

```
class Test {
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;
  //there are quite a few variables here.
}

...

std::map<std::string, double Test::*> members;
members["a"] = &Test::a;
members["b"] = &Test::b;
members["c"] = &Test::c;
...

std::string input = ...;
Test test;

auto iter = members.find(input);
if (iter != members.end())
{
    auto ptr = iter->second;
    return test.*ptr;
}
else
{
    // return something else, or throw ...
}
```